# Upload a binary to app store if already a version is ready for sale?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I have uploaded my app version 1.0 which is approved by Apple but I haven't released yet to the users. I have another version 1.1 with the hot fix.

**1. Is it possible to upload version 1.1 before releasing 1.0 to the user?

2. Will binary be rejected if I try to upload the binary version 1.1?**

Comment: No binary will not be rejected. Upload your build with newer version and submit it for App review.

Comment: Agree with Pallavi, should not cause a problem.

Comment: Can you give any reference from Apple? or anyone has experienced the same scenario?

Comment: @jailani see my answer which i posted through my past experience with same situations. Will work surely in your case

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your can it seems like you already got approval from Apple review team. Its true that you haven't released your app yet in market but still if you needs to submit new binary & update you will have to again send for review & get approval.

So i guess you have set up the manual release of an app.

So my opinion is create new binary with new version & send new version for approval.

Once you get approval for the new bug free version you should release it publicly for users.

> 1. Yes its possible to upload 1.1 before release 1.0
> 2. No binary will not get rejected

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I will upload the binary and check. Thanks for your answer.